# Opensolaris snmp broadcast

Tags: opensolaris

A network sensor I'm evaluating is showing that my Opensolaris server is broadcasting on the snmp port 161, and I'm getting alerts about every 2 minutes.  How can I turn off the snmp broadcast (i.e. traps?) on the Opensolaris machine?

We have snmp enabled on the Opensolaris machine for Cacti, so it should really just be acting like a client in regards to snmp.  Is there a configuration setting somewhere?  I'm not familiar with snmp, but somehow got it up and running for Cacti.  I see that /usr/sbin/snmpd is running.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check all services running and try disabling each of them one at a time, starting with the most suspicious. Some googling suggests:

```
/etc/rc3.d/S76snmpdx stop
/etc/rc3.d/S77dmi stop
```

(assuming you are in runlevel 3)